# Open a program (cqwr.exe) using command button, MS Access Error "Invalid procedure call or argument"

Tags: vba, ms-access, command

I have this program in this directory ("C:\Program Files\CQCS\7.22-8B_client\cqwr.exe")

I created a command button on MS Access to open this program, this is my code

```
Private Sub Command79_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command79_Click
Dim stAppName As String
stAppName = "C:\Program Files\CQCS\7.22-8B_client\cqwr.exe"
Call Shell(stAppName, 1)
Exit_Command79_Click:
Exit Sub
Err_Command79_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Command79_Click 
End Sub
```

When I click on the button, I get this error "Invalid procedure call or argument"

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thank You

Comment: Works for me (with a program that's on my computer). Run the menu Debug / Compile, perhaps there is a compile error elsewhere?

Comment: Can you send me the sample path link you used? I'm thinking my problem could be the path.

Comment: `stAppName = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Minesweeper\MineSweeper.exe"` :D

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you may have already done this but have you double checked the path by going the exe file and looking at properties to compare paths.